# custom post single page

Tags: posts

Very new to WP and AP theme development.

I am in the process of creating a theme based on a custom post type.

this is my function.php

```
            /**
             * Defines theme version.
             */
        define( 'TUTORIALEE', '1.0.0' );

        if ( ! isset( $content_width ) )
            $content_width = 800; /* pixels */

        if ( ! function_exists( 'tutorialee_setup' ) ) :
        /**
         * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
         *
         * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which runs
         * before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, such as indicating
         * support post thumbnails.
         */
        function tutorialee_setup() {

            /**
             * Make theme available for translation.
             * Translations can be placed in the /languages/ directory.
             */
            load_theme_textdomain( 'tutorialee', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

            /**
             * Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to <head>.
             */
            add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

            /**
             * Enable support for post thumbnails and featured images.
             */
            add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

            /**
             * Add support for two custom navigation menus.
             */
            register_nav_menus( array(
                'primary'   => __( 'Primary Menu', 'tutorialee' ),
                'secondary' => __('Secondary Menu', 'tutorialee' )
            ) );

            /**
             * Enable support for the following post formats:
             * aside, gallery, quote, image, and video
             */
            add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array ( 'aside', 'gallery', 'quote', 'image', 'video' ) );
        }
        endif; // tutorialee_setup
        add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'tutorialee_setup' );





        class MySettingsPage
        {
            /**
             * Holds the values to be used in the fields callbacks
             */
            private $options;

            /**
             * Start up
             */
            public function __construct()
            {
                add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_plugin_page' ) );
                add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'page_init' ) );
            }

            /**
             * Add options page
             */
            public function add_plugin_page()
            {
                // This page will be under "Settings"
                add_options_page(
                    'Settings Admin', 
                    'My Settingsz', 
                    'manage_options', 
                    'my-setting-admin', 
                    array( $this, 'create_admin_page' )
                );
            }

            /**
             * Options page callback
             */
            public function create_admin_page()
            {
                // Set class property
                $this->options = get_option( 'my_option_name' );
                ?>
                <div class="wrap">
                    <h1>My Settings</h1>
                    <form method="post" action="options.php">
                    <?php
                        // This prints out all hidden setting fields
                        settings_fields( 'my_option_group' );
                        do_settings_sections( 'my-setting-admin' );
                        submit_button();
                    ?>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <?php
            }

            /**
             * Register and add settings
             */
            public function page_init()
            {        
                register_setting(
                    'my_option_group', // Option group
                    'my_option_name', // Option name
                    array( $this, 'sanitize' ) // Sanitize
                );

                add_settings_section(
                    'setting_section_id', // ID
                    'My Custom Settings', // Title
                    array( $this, 'print_section_info' ), // Callback
                    'my-setting-admin' // Page
                );  

                add_settings_field(
                    'id_number', // ID
                    'ID Number', // Title 
                    array( $this, 'id_number_callback' ), // Callback
                    'my-setting-admin', // Page
                    'setting_section_id' // Section           
                );      

                add_settings_field(
                    'title', 
                    'Title', 
                    array( $this, 'title_callback' ), 
                    'my-setting-admin', 
                    'setting_section_id'
                );      
            }

            /**
             * Sanitize each setting field as needed
             *
             * @param array $input Contains all settings fields as array keys
             */
            public function sanitize( $input )
            {
                $new_input = array();
                if( isset( $input['id_number'] ) )
                    $new_input['id_number'] = absint( $input['id_number'] );

                if( isset( $input['title'] ) )
                    $new_input['title'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['title'] );

                return $new_input;
            }

            /** 
             * Print the Section text
             */
            public function print_section_info()
            {
                print 'Enter your settings below:';
            }

            /** 
             * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
             */
            public function id_number_callback()
            {
                printf(
                    '<input type="text" id="id_number" name="my_option_name[id_number]" value="%s" />',
                    isset( $this->options['id_number'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['id_number']) : ''
                );
            }

            /** 
             * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
             */
            public function title_callback()
            {
                printf(
                    '<input type="text" id="title" name="my_option_name[title]" value="%s" />',
                    isset( $this->options['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['title']) : ''
                );
            }
        }

        if( is_admin() )
            $my_settings_page = new MySettingsPage();


        // Adding Custom Post Type for Tutorials Listing

        function my_custom_post_tutorial() {

           //labels array added inside the function and precedes args array

           $labels = array(
            'name'               => _x( 'Tutorials', 'post type general name' ),
            'singular_name'      => _x( 'Tutorial', 'post type singular name' ),
            'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Tutorial' ),
            'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Tutorial' ),
            'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Tutorial' ),
            'new_item'           => __( 'New Tutorial' ),
            'all_items'          => __( 'All Tutorials' ),
            'view_item'          => __( 'View Tutorial' ),
            'search_items'       => __( 'Search tutorials' ),
            'not_found'          => __( 'No tutorials found' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No tutorials found in the Trash' ),
            'parent_item_colon'  => '',
            'menu_name'          => 'Tutorials'
          );

                 // args array

           $args = array(
            'labels'        => $labels,
            'description'   => 'Displays tutorials',
            'public'        => true,
            'menu_position' => 4,
            'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
            'has_archive'   => false,
          );

          register_post_type( 'tutorial', $args );
        }
        add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_tutorial' );



        //creating custom taxonomies for tutorials custom post

           //registration of taxonomies

        function my_taxonomies_tutorial() {

            //labels array

        $labels = array(
            'name'              => _x( 'Tutorial Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Tutorial  Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Search Tutorial Categories' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'All Tutorial Categories' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Tutorial Category' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Tutorial Category:' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Tutorial Category' ),
            'update_item'       => __( 'Update Tutorial Category' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Tutorial Category' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Tutorial Category' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( ' Tutorial Categories' ),
          );

           //args array

        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'hierarchical' => true,
          );

          register_taxonomy( 'tutorial_category', 'tutorial', $args );
        }

        add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_tutorial', 0 );
```

and I have a single-tutorial.php file that if I understand correctly is supposed to be called upon as the template for any of the custom tutorialee posts. But when I go to the permalink I just get the index.php code.

Please help.

Comment: Did you flush rewrite rules?

Comment: just try saving the permalink again.

Comment: @Milo flushing rewrite rules did the trick. Be kind and write this as an answer. Newbies like me might find this helpfull

Comment: You have to flush rewrite rules and your problem will be solved :) .

Answer (score 0):

You can flush the rewrite rules with this code

```
flush_rewrite_rules();
```